# pygtk hide/destroy doesn't work

Tags: python, window, pygtk

I'm trying to open an Dialog and after getting the response back, closing it again.
As far as I understood it, .destroy() or .hide() should remove the window from the screen. But the window freezes and stays open. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gtk
import time

class MyWindow(gtk.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, filename="Filename.jpg"):
        gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "Window", parent, 0,
            (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,
             gtk.STOCK_OK, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))

        self.set_default_size(150, 100)
        box = self.get_content_area()

        self.usr_label = gtk.Label("User-Name:\t")
        self.usr_entry = gtk.Entry()
        box.add(self.usr_label)
        box.add(self.usr_entry)

        self.show_all()


dialog = MyWindow(filename="foobar")
response = dialog.run()
if response != gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
       exit()
dialog.hide()
dialog.destroy()
time.sleep(15)
print("foo")
```

Comment: Do you have a `gtk.main()` somewhere?

Comment: @Cilyan No – do I need it and where?

Comment: I did not post an answer because I'm 100% sure, but I believe you still need a main loop. See the example here: http://zetcode.com/gui/pygtk/dialogs/

Comment: Your code works for me (Py 2.7 win32 Gtk 2.24.2), and similar code works on Py 3.3 win32 Gtk 3.6.4 (GI). You probably want however to hide and destroy your dialog also when clicking Cancel (check response afterwards), but the main loop isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gtk, time;

class MyWindow(gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, filename="Filename.jpg"):
        gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "Window", parent, 0,
            (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                gtk.STOCK_OK, gtk.RESPONSE_OK));

        self.connect("destroy", self.quit);
        self.connect("response", self.response);

        self.set_default_size(150, 100)
        box = self.get_content_area()

        self.usr_label = gtk.Label("User-Name:\t")
        self.usr_entry = gtk.Entry()
        box.add(self.usr_label)
        box.add(self.usr_entry)

        self.show_all();

    def response(self, widget = None, data = None):
        if data == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            name = self.usr_entry.get_text();
            print("User-Name: " + name);
            self.quit();
        else:
            self.quit()

    def main(self): gtk.main();
    def quit(self, widget = None): gtk.main_quit();

if __name__ == '__main__': MyWindow().main();
```